# Dynamic binding for dynamic query on Native Dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, dynamic-binding

I find myself in a situation where my code needs to execute a dynamic statement formed by an unknown number (at least one, but could be more) of other dynamic statements concatenated by 'intersect' and 'union' operators.

Here's an example with three querys (I know that this could be resolved with one query, I'm trying to keep it simple):

```
sql1 varchar2(500) := 'select empno from emp where deptno = :1';
sql2 varchar2(500) := 'select empno from emp where sal > :2 and hiredate >=:3'; 
sql3 varchar2(500) := 'select empno from emp where sal <= :2 and hiredate =:3'
realStatement varchar(1500) := sql1 || ' insersect ' || sql2 || ' union ' sql3;
```

Now, given that the number of sub-statements it's unknown at run time, but all the binding variables values are known (i.e. deptno, sal and hiredate will always be :1, :2 and :3 respectively). I can't use the 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE realStatement USING' form because it's bindings are positional and, for this example, I should pass the sal and hiredate parameters twice, resulting in the statement:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE realStatement USING l_deptno,l_sal,l_hiredate,l_sal,l_hiredate;
```

Which there's no way I could know beforehand to include all the repetitions for every sub-statement.

I know that I could use the DBMS_SQL package with the bind() function but the performance it's 1.5 to 3 times worst than with native dynamic (from oracle docs), and in this case the performance is relevant.

So what I'm actually doing is replacing all the ':1' occurrences with l_deptno, all the ':2' occurrences with l_sal, and all ':3' occurrences with 'to_date(''' || l_hiredate || ''',''DD/MM/YYYY'')' in the realStatement string before executing it like this:

```
realStatement := replace(realStatement,':1',l_deptno);
realStatement := replace(realStatement,':2',l_sal);
realStatement := replace(realStatement,':3','to_date(''' || l_hiredate || ''',''DD/MM/YYYY'')');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE realStatement;
```

But I'm not sure that this is the best solution, questions:

1. is there a way to improve the performance or to pass the bindings
   dynamically using native dynamic SQL?
2. will the use of the DBSM_SQL package result in a better performance
   than that of the chosen solution?

Comment: Would `sql1 varchar2(500) := 'select empno from emp where deptno = ' || :1` satisfy your need?

Comment: @Politank-Z I forgot to mention that the query string is recovered from a table so the reference is already there, plus it wouldn't necessarily be always at the end of the query

Comment: Where did you red about the performance degradation for bind() function?

Comment: @Wernfried here's the 9i doc version, I couldn't find the updated one http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite your statements:

```
sql1 varchar2(500) := 'select empno from emp where deptno = :1';
sql2 varchar2(500) := 'select empno from emp where sal > :2 and hiredate >=:3'; 
sql3 varchar2(500) := 'select empno from emp where sal <= :2 and hiredate =:3'
realStatement varchar(1500) := sql1 || ' insersect ' || sql2 || ' union ' sql3;
```

to utilise `WITH` clause as follows:

```
sql0 varchar2(500) := 'WITH par AS (SELECT :1 AS P1, :2 AS P2, :3 AS P3 FROM dual)';
sql1 varchar2(500) := '(select empno from emp join par where deptno = par.p1)';
sql2 varchar2(500) := '(select empno from emp join par where sal > par.p2 and hiredate >=par.p3)'; 
sql3 varchar2(500) := '(select empno from emp join par where sal <= par.p2 and hiredate = par.p3)';
realStatement varchar(2000) := sql0 || ', sql1 as ' || sql1 || ', sql2 as ' || sql2 || ', sql3 as ' || sql3 || ' select * from sql1 intersect select * from sql2 union select * from sql3';
```

or (when no reuse of subqueries):

```
sql0 varchar2(500) := 'WITH par AS (SELECT :1 AS P1, :2 AS P2, :3 AS P3 FROM dual)';
sql1 varchar2(500) := 'select empno from emp join par where deptno = par.p1';
sql2 varchar2(500) := 'select empno from emp join par where sal > par.p2 and hiredate >=par.p3'; 
sql3 varchar2(500) := 'select empno from emp join par where sal <= par.p2 and hiredate = par.p3';
realStatement varchar(2000) := sql0 || ' ' || sql1 || ' intersect ' || sql2 || ' union ' || sql3;
```

then execute it using 3 bind variables: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE realStatement USING l_deptno,l_sal,l_hiredate`

Comment: Hi Pavel, thank you for answering. I'll try it and come back to you, looks promising though

Comment: Hi Pavel, I've tried your suggestion and partially worked, what I had to change though is how the values from the with clause are referenced in the subquerys.The "par.p1" reference wont be resolved, it has to be referenced as "select p1 from par". Which (from what I've read) is how the with clause works anyways, if you correct this on your answer I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: @Typo sorry, I hadn't time to try, I added the missing `join par` to each subquery (you can replace `join par where` with `join par on` too, I did not want to change the statements too much)

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, Oracle documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dynamic_sql.htm#BJEBACEH) says:

> Programs that use native dynamic SQL are much faster than programs that use the DBMS_SQL package. Typically, native dynamic SQL statements perform 1.5 to 3 times better than equivalent DBMS_SQL calls.

But from other side - you can see some comparision here: http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/w/toad_for_oracle_wiki/231.dbms-sql-vs-execute-immediate.aspx:

> There are many advantages to using DBMS_SQL over EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :
>
> - It's easier to spell and type (for me anyway - I can't spell IMMEDAITE IMMEADIATE IMMEDIATE
> - Less latching with DBMS_SQL.
> - Fewer parses with DBMS_SQL.
> - Better scaling of your app with DBMS_SQL because of the above.
>
> Disadvantages :
>
> - More typing overall with DBMS_SQL.

I would like to say - if you have many such calls, then binding variables and reducing parse count will give significant impact. But - if you don't have many calls and single query returns many rows - then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE without bind variables (your solution with replace) can be faster.

In any case - if performance is relevant - make both solutions (with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and DBMS_SQL) and compare results.

Answer (score 0):

When I was in a training several years ago, the performance difference was a topic (it was Oracle 9i). We were able to reproduce the difference. However when I do the same tests today (with Oracle 11) I don't get any performance difference anymore. Use the way which is more convenient for you.

Comment: what tests did you perfomed?

Comment: I run the same query as with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and with `DBMS_SQL` several times -> no difference. 10 years ago with Oracle 9i the difference was significant.